# CSS text line height and padding problem how can I solve?

Tags: css, fonts, height

as shown in the pictures below, there is a height problem? I couldn't figure this out using line-height.
Is there another css feature that affects this?

I want to do exactly what I want to remove the gaps 20px when I give an element to 23px, 24px that causes space problems.

[click to see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoP5P.png)

Used Font: [Nunito](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nunito)

Comment: Can you show us your `HTML` in a working example?

Comment: I did not give the red box a blank space as seen in the running example, but can I reset the space there?
[HTML](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZPRbEy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm seeing no gaps when `line-height: 1` is used on the `h2` in your example.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:300,400,600,700,800,900&subset=latin-ext');

body {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
}

.price {
  background-color: #c7c7c7;
  display: inline-flex;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 23px;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="price">
  $21,191
</h2>
```

Comment: @dogukanb By the way, you don't need to use `inline-flex`. I just used it so that the `h2` text wouldn't take up an entire row.